# Module 'react' does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: linkedin-api, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to do LinkedIn integration in my app.
So, I have done as below :

Installed dependency as below :

**npm install react-native-linkedin --save;**

So, while launching the app, am getting below error :

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?
platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false)with
error:(Unable to resolve module 'react' from
'mypath/App.js':Module 'react' does not exist
in the Haste module map
```

What might be the issue ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command in terminal and try again

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```